# How to find the home page of a site? I want to use the Rest API OR the classic interface

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, administration, sitepages, classic-experience

My site has many pages, I want to know the homepage of the site, is there any way?

I want to use REST API OR the classic interface.

Comment: Try below and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharePoint REST API endpoint like below to check the home page of your SharePoint site:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web?$select=WelcomePage
```

You can also run above endpoint directly within browser tab and get the home page name.

**Output**:

[image]

`WelcomePage` property shows the home page name. In above image, `SitePages` is the library name and `Home.aspx` is the home page name.

Comment: Thank you bro, it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the data from the current site you are on, there is a property that contains the Flag where it says '***isWebWelcomePage***'.

You can skip the waiting time of querying the data by requesting an API.

You can directly get it from SharePoint pageContext that is available data in all SharePoint page.

I got the info from [here](https://tipsbybits.com/other/actually-its-already-in-the-sharepoint-pagecontext/).

Look into the

```
context.pageContext.legacyPageContext
```

object property.

Happy SharePointing!